# Mass scan of SSL certificates hangs in Golang

Tags: http, ssl, go, microservices

I'm writing a microservice for validating SSL certificates for URLs, basically combining together these two things:

- An implementation of an SSL checker from here:
  https://github.com/alanorth/check-tls-certs/blob/master/main.go
- And
  this approach for spawning workers from an API call:
  https://medium.com/smsjunk/handling-1-million-requests-per-minute-with-golang-f70ac505fcaa

So, practically I'm launching the small service, which accepts a list of URLs and validates SSL certificates for them. The problem is, after some requests the SSL checker starts freezing for quite a long time, and I don't know why (each payload in this log is **the same set of 5000 URLs** every time):

```
DEBUG: 2018/09/29 14:33:58 dispatcher.go:34: DNS timeout set to 10 seconds
DEBUG: 2018/09/29 14:33:58 dispatcher.go:35: SSL timeout set to 10 seconds
DEBUG: 2018/09/29 14:33:58 dispatcher.go:36: HTTP timeout set to 10 seconds
DEBUG: 2018/09/29 14:33:58 dispatcher.go:37: Starting 10000 workers...
DEBUG: 2018/09/29 14:33:58 api.go:113: Starting API at :8888...
DEBUG: 2018/09/29 14:34:04 api.go:50: Received request, starting task '0af84d1e-52b3-41bc-935c-a5a22a007a2c'...
DEBUG: 2018/09/29 14:34:08 api.go:50: Received request, starting task 'e2379281-f98d-4185-8776-46c032bf6bf9'...
DEBUG: 2018/09/29 14:34:11 api.go:50: Received request, starting task 'faeb6b1d-8567-427f-81b7-63cdc2154314'...
DEBUG: 2018/09/29 14:34:15 api.go:50: Received request, starting task '702ca7b2-4b23-434c-9921-e72532766b16'...
DEBUG: 2018/09/29 14:34:15 dispatcher.go:59: Finished processing URLs for task '0af84d1e-52b3-41bc-935c-a5a22a007a2c' (took 11 seconds)!
DEBUG: 2018/09/29 14:34:20 dispatcher.go:59: Finished processing URLs for task 'e2379281-f98d-4185-8776-46c032bf6bf9' (took 12 seconds)!
DEBUG: 2018/09/29 14:34:22 api.go:50: Received request, starting task 'aa2a6bd6-f207-41a4-9dd4-a48ad72b85de'...
DEBUG: 2018/09/29 14:34:29 dispatcher.go:59: Finished processing URLs for task '702ca7b2-4b23-434c-9921-e72532766b16' (took 14 seconds)!
DEBUG: 2018/09/29 14:34:33 dispatcher.go:59: Finished processing URLs for task 'aa2a6bd6-f207-41a4-9dd4-a48ad72b85de' (took 11 seconds)!
DEBUG: 2018/09/29 14:34:55 api.go:50: Received request, starting task 'ea8c7c69-c533-4c9e-a4e4-439b41df2f52'...
DEBUG: 2018/09/29 14:34:59 api.go:50: Received request, starting task '6f2a2374-6911-4ff4-bbe2-b3aa378a2938'...
DEBUG: 2018/09/29 14:35:01 api.go:50: Received request, starting task '73cae838-9971-403f-bdfd-6e4790624fe8'...
DEBUG: 2018/09/29 14:35:04 api.go:50: Received request, starting task 'ee04997d-efd2-47df-9359-b46c90859224'...
DEBUG: 2018/09/29 14:35:06 dispatcher.go:59: Finished processing URLs for task 'ea8c7c69-c533-4c9e-a4e4-439b41df2f52' (took 11 seconds)!
DEBUG: 2018/09/29 14:35:07 api.go:50: Received request, starting task '5918b20d-ab52-484a-888e-2651344e8c5e'...
DEBUG: 2018/09/29 14:35:09 dispatcher.go:59: Finished processing URLs for task '6f2a2374-6911-4ff4-bbe2-b3aa378a2938' (took 10 seconds)!
DEBUG: 2018/09/29 14:35:19 dispatcher.go:59: Finished processing URLs for task 'ee04997d-efd2-47df-9359-b46c90859224' (took 15 seconds)!
DEBUG: 2018/09/29 14:35:20 dispatcher.go:59: Finished processing URLs for task '5918b20d-ab52-484a-888e-2651344e8c5e' (took 13 seconds)!
DEBUG: 2018/09/29 14:50:06 dispatcher.go:59: Finished processing URLs for task 'faeb6b1d-8567-427f-81b7-63cdc2154314' (took 955 seconds)!
DEBUG: 2018/09/29 14:50:57 dispatcher.go:59: Finished processing URLs for task '73cae838-9971-403f-bdfd-6e4790624fe8' (took 956 seconds)!
```

I have a timeout set to `time.Second * 10` which I'm passing to `net.DialTimeout()`, but it doesn't save the day. That means, instead of this line: https://github.com/alanorth/check-tls-certs/blob/master/main.go#L232 I have something like this:

```
ipConn,err := net.DialTimeout("tcp", result.Domain + ":443", time.Second * 10)
if err != nil {
    result.Errors["ssl"] = append(result.Errors["ssl"], err.Error())
    if s.FailIfInvalid {
        result.Success = false
    }
    return
}

tc := &tls.Config{ServerName: result.Domain}
if s.CheckInsecure {
    tc.InsecureSkipVerify = true
}

conn:= tls.Client(ipConn, tc)

err = conn.Handshake()
if err != nil {
    switch e := err.(type) {
    case x509.CertificateInvalidError:
        result.Errors["ssl"] = append(result.Errors["ssl"], e.Error())
        if s.FailIfInvalid {
            result.Success = false
        }
        return
}
defer conn.Close()
```

Also, `strace` on running thread says it hangs on `epoll_pwait()` syscall, and `pprof` gives me nothing, because the application itself is peacefully waiting in userspace during this time.

What should I do next to properly fix the issue? It doesn't seem to have anything to do with opened file descriptors or anything (the numbers are reasonable), also memory/CPU consumption is pretty low. Would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Have you run `strace` on all the threads to see what's happening when it freezes? Have you looked at a stack trace when it freezes? What profiles have you generated with pprof? CPU time and blocking profile must show something.

Comment: The answers to all these questions are in the text. Like, strace shows that one thread is hanging on epoll_pwait() while others are waiting on futex(). CPU time pprof dump gives nothing, because app hangs on syscall, not inside a userspace code.

Comment: Yes, one thread will be in epoll, because that is the network poller. Regardless of what's blocked in a syscall, the syscall originates from _some_ go function call, and you want the time in your code's function to know which is blocked. The Stack trace will also show the status (and often the time in that status) of each goroutine.

Comment: Good idea, I'll check the stack trace and post info here, thanks! It's just weird CPU profiling doesn't give any results.

Comment: You are not always closing connections when the handshake fails. Defer the Close call before calling Handshake().

Comment: Does the behavior depend on the URL you test? Because it could as well be a DNS resolution timeout...